# Affecting all-but-one-element with jQuery's each()

Tags: jquery, html

A quick question about jQuery's `each()` function;

When I use `each()`, it's usually because I want to affect all the elements apart from just one. For instance:

```
$("a.aboutMenu").each(function () {
    $(this).css("color","#FFF");
});

$(this).css("color","#111");
```

Is there a shorthand way of writing this better? I realise I could put an `if` in the `each` function, but there must be someway of writing "`each` except `$(this)`"?

Comment: Does the element you dont want to change have any different attributes to the rest?

Comment: No, it's just a menu that's been selected and now I want to look different from the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is exactly the same thing if you see on the jQuery API.

In your example you are saying: for each a.aboutMenu to change the css color to be white.

You can also write:

```
$.each('a.aboutMenu', function() { $(this).css("color","#FFF");} });
```

If you need a control just add an `if` inside your function.

---

EDIT:

To remove just `this` element you can write:

```
$('.aboutMenu').not(this).css('color', '#FFF');
```

or better:

```
$('.aboutMenu').not(this).addClass('whiteColor');
```

Answer (score 6):

In this circumstance you don't even need `each`, but in general you could exclude `this` from the selector using `not()`, and in the same step apply it's CSS:

```
$("a.aboutMenu").not($(this).css('color', '#111')).each(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
});​
```

This works because using `css()` as a setter returns the original jQuery object, which fits as a parameter to [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not) quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do the following:

```
$("a.aboutMenu").not( $(this) ).each(function () {
     $(this).css("color","#FFF");
});
$(this).css("color","#111");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
$("a.aboutMenu").css("color","#FFF");
$(this).css("color","#111");
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the typical `.each()` method, in some cases using `.siblings()` works out better. Especially in cases where you want to target everything except one specific element.

For example:

```js
$('a.aboutMenu').on('click', function() {
  // the initiating element..
  this.css('color','#ddd');

  // all anchor siblings..
  this.siblings('a').css('color','#fff');

  // the initiating element and all '.menu' siblings..
  this.css('color','#ddd').siblings('a.menu').css('color','#fff');
});
```

Naturally, this is a simple example that doesn't cater for elements that would not (or should not) be updated, but the key point is that you can work from a single entry point (a clicked element, the currently active element, etc..) and then make your modifications to all of it's siblings.

Perhaps a little bit out of the scope of this question, but this could even be extended using some creative selector naming. Keeping in mind that both `$('.menu-about')` and `$('[class=|"menu"]')` would match a class selector such as 'menu-about' (see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs) for details), you could create a single, small, easily reusable style update function that caters for virtually any menu layout.